# Definite integral involving indicator and maximum functions.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the expected revenue from a model with the integral below:
$$R = \phi \bigg[ \int_0^1 \int_0^1  \frac{max(  2v_2-1+\phi, \phi) }{1+\phi} {\bf 1}(v_1 \geq \frac{\phi}{1+\phi}) {\bf 1}\left( v_2 \leq max(\frac{v_1 + \phi v_1 - \phi+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \right) dv_1 dv_2 +  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 max(\frac{v_1+\phi v_1 - \phi +1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) {\bf 1}(v_2 \geq \frac{1}{2}) {\bf 1} \left( v_1 \leq max( \frac{2 v_2 -1 + \phi}{1+ \phi } , \frac{\phi}{1+\phi} ) \right)  dv_1 dv_2 \bigg] + (1- \phi) \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} {\bf 1} (v_2 \geq \frac{1}{2}) dv_2 $$
Firstly, let me note that $v_1$ and $v_2$ follow a uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, and are independent. $\phi$ is a probability and ranges over $[0,1]$. After simplification of indicator functions, I ended with the expression below:
$$\phi \bigg[\int_{\frac{\phi}{1+\phi}}^1 max(  \frac{2v_2-1+\phi}{1+\phi}, \frac{\phi }{1+\phi})\frac{v_1 + \phi v_1 - \phi+1}{2} dv_1 +  \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 max(\frac{v_1 + \phi v_1 - \phi+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \frac{2v_2 - 1 + \phi}{1+\phi} dv_2 \bigg] + (1-\phi)\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{1}{2}dv_2$$
At that point, I am trying to deal with the integration of a maximum function. I came up with various sources for alike problems, but my problems differ from them, as the variable in the maximum function is different from the one we integrate over. Nonetheless, I used
$$ \max{\left(f(x),g(x)\right)} = \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}+\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}
 $$ to compute the integral as:
$$\phi \bigg[\int_{\frac{\phi}{1+\phi}}^1 (\frac{2v_2 - 1 + 2\phi}{2+2\phi} + \frac{|2v_2-1|}{2+2\phi})\frac{v_1 + \phi v_1 - \phi+1}{2} dv_1 +  \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 (\frac{v_1 + \phi v_1 - \phi+2}{4} + \frac{|v_1 + \phi v_1 - \phi|}{4})\frac{2v_2 - 1 + \phi}{1+\phi} dv_2 \bigg] + (1-\phi)\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{1}{2}dv_2 $$
But when I compute the integral I still have $v_1$ in the output. Tools such as Wolfram Mathematica compute the integral without having a variable at the end, and I am curious if there is a way to manually compute the integral as the tools do.

Comment: Notice then when you get from the first expression to the second you transform a double integral over $v_1,v_2$ into single integrals, over either $v_1$ or $v_2$, but both integrals contain both $v_1$ and $v_2$. There is your mistake.